# Как убрать ошибку при отсутствии нужного ключа в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Существуют словари

`file = {"One":"1" , "Two":"2", "Three": "3"}`

`file_two = {"One" : 1, "Two" : "2"}`

Дальше необходимо сравнить значение ключей

```
if (file['One']) > (file_two['One']):
    print ("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Но при такой ситуации

```
if (file['Three']) > (file_two['Three']):
    print ("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Появляется ошибка, так как во втором словаре отсутствует ключ "Three".
Как можно сделать, что бы при отсутствии ключа, не выдавалась ошибка? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибку лучше обрабатывать, а не подавлять.

```
try:
    if (file['Three']) > (file_two['Three']):
        print ("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
except KeyError as e:
    print("Отсутствует значение", e)
```

выведет, а ошибка счтаться не будет - программа продолжится

```
Отсутствует значение 'Three'
```

Если пропуски данных не важны, то можно исправить словарь.

Кроме замены [] скобок на `.get(key, default)` на словорях есть метод `__missing__(self, key)` который вызывеатся когда нет соответсвующего ключа. Этот метод можно реализовать в своем классе на основе `dict`. Но есть и готовый в модуле `collections`

```
from collections import defaultdict

file = defaultdict(lambda: 0, {"One":"1" , "Two":"2", "Three": "3"})
file_two = defaultdict(lambda: 0, {"One" : 1, "Two" : "2"})

file['afanana'] == 0
```

Конструктор `defaultdict()` принимает первым аргументом функцию которая будет возвращать отсутствующее значение. После обращения к элементу значение добавляется в словарь.

Если такое поведение не нужно - делайте класс с `__missing__`:

```
class default0(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 0

file = default0({"One":"1" , "Two":"2", "Three": "3"})
file_two = default0( {"One" : 1, "Two" : "2"})

file['afanana'] == 0
```

Ну и для тяжелых случаев можно перегрузить `__getitem__`:

```
class default1(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        return 0
```

Этот способ можно использовать для динамической генерации словаря.

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать метод `.get()` словарей

```
if file.get('Three', 0) > file_two.get('Three', 0):
    print ("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Метод `.get()` принимает **ключ для поиска** и **значение, которое будет, если ключа нет**, т.е. `file.get('Three', 0)` вернет `0`, если ключ `Three` не найден в словаре.

Answer (score 1):

```py
if 'Three' not in file_two or 'Three' not in file:
    print ("No data")
elif (file['Three']) > (file_two['Three']):
    print ("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: идея правильная, но реализация хромает... можно исправлю?

Comment: @eri, благодарю. Не стал так углубляться, поскольку задача звучала как "что-бы не было ошибки". Ваш вариант, безусловно, более продуманный.